# My code to open a new window is having no effect. can anyone spot my mistake?

Tags: javascript, input, popup

I have this code:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Pre-Requisites" onClick="window.open('pre_requisites.php','pre-requisites','width=670px,height=470px,left=0px,top=100px,screenX=0,screenY=100')">
```

It is use to open a new page to allow users to view information of the items they are applying for. A popup window will be useful in this case as user will be able to reference to the materials in the new window while deciding which permit to apply for.

But with that input, no matter how i click the window won't open. May I know what is my mistake?

BTW I did not add anything `<script></script>` to the head tag...is that a possible error?

Comment: Check that your web browser allows popups. If not, JavaScript will throw an exception that you should really try to catch.

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/83pxC/

Comment: Me too, in Chrome, but not in IE 9.

Comment: hmmfor me i am using IE 9...Chumiku is right...if i change the name of the window to prerequisites instead of pre_requisites it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the window must be alphanumeric for maximum compatibility. So

```
window.open('pre_requisites.php','prerequisites','width=670px,height=470px,left=0px,top=100px,screenX=0,screenY=100')
```

it should be works

Answer (score 0):

If I look on [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) page, I don't see the **top**, **left**, **screenX** or **screenY** settings.
Maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), there is no screenX and screenY settings. Also, drop "px" everywhere:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Pre-Requisites" onClick="window.open('pre_requisites.php','pre-requisites','width=670,height=470,left=0,top=100')">
```

Have not tested it though.